# Passing an array of pointers to a Class Object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

Hoping someone can help a beginner out here. I searched but some of the solutions were out of scope my knowledge. I'm trying to create a function which will take in a an array of pointers to a class object and output a `getName()` function for each object. But I keep getting a "**no instance of overloaded function**". I can't figure out what the problem is. Please take a look at following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

void getName(Student *studentArray[], int); //prototype                 

int main()
{           
    //Creates class objects with Constructors Name and Score
    //Class object has a function getName() to return name 
    Student stud1("John", 100);
    Student stud2("Mary", 90);
    Student stud3 ("Jack", 85);

    //Create an array of student objects 
    Student myArray[3]= {stud1, stud2, stud3};

    //ERROR HERE NO INSTANCE OF OVERLOADED FUNCTON
    getName(myArray, 3) 

    return 0;        
}

void getName(Student *studentsArray[], int arraySize)
{    
    for(int index=0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        cout << studentsArray[index]->getName() << endl;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your prototype doesn't match your function for a start...

Comment: And... you have an array of `Student`, not an array of pointer-to-`Student`

Comment: What's the syntax for array of pointer to student?

Comment: Try `Student* myArray[] = {&stud1, ...};`

Comment: And yes, if you think the syntax is confusing, you are not alone.

Comment: `std::array` has a more natural syntax.or even `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Student *studentsArray[]` is an array of pointers to students:

[-> "John", -> "Mary", -> "Jack"]

While `Student *studentsArray` is a pointer to a student (e.g. the first of an array):

-> [ "John", "Mary", "Jack" ]

using the `[]` operator you can jump to the offset relative to a pointer

```
studentsArray[0] == (*studentsArray)
studentsArray[1] == *(studentsArray+1)
studentsArray[2] == *(studentsArray+2)
```

and the `->` operator is syntactic sugar for `(*var).`

The problem is that you created an array of students instead of an array of pointers of students:

```
Student myArray[3] = {stud1, stud2, stud3};
```

should actually be

```
Student* myArray[3] = { &stud1, &stud2, &stud3 };
```

Here is a full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getName(Student *studentsArray[], int); //prototype 

int main()
{

    //Creates class objects with Constructors Name and Score
    //Class object has a function getName() to return name 
    Student stud1("John", 100);
    Student stud2("Mary", 90);
    Student stud3("Jack", 85);

    //Create an array of student objects 
    Student* myArray[3] = { &stud1, &stud2, &stud3 };

    getName(myArray, 3);
    return 0;
}

void getName(Student *studentsArray[], int arraySize)
{

    for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        cout << studentsArray[index]->getName() << endl;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that your pointer doesn't actually point any existing variable or its address. In this case, pointer will instead point a randomly chosen memory cell address, so it's really dangerous because you will never know what it will cause, including data lose, memory leak and so on.

Answer (score 0):

With `std::vector`, it would be something like:

```
#include "Student.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void displayNames(const std::vector<Student>& students);

int main()
{           
    Student stud1("John", 100);
    Student stud2("Mary", 90);
    Student stud3("Jack", 85);

    std::vector<Student> students = {stud1, stud2, stud3};

    displayNames(students);

    return 0;
}

void displayNames(const std::vector<Student>& students)
{    
    for (const auto& student : students)
    {
        std::cout << student.getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```